# How does one test Angular 2 with Mocha?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, mocha.js, systemjs

I've been banging my head against this for a few days, and just can't get anywhere.. I'm trying to use Mocha to test my Angular 2 app (SystemJS-based if it matters), and I just can't figure out how to get instances of controllers.

I'm trying the simplest case I can come up with;

```
import {bootstrap} from 'angular2/platform/browser';
import {App} from '../app/app';
import {Type} from 'angular2/core';

describe('Login', () => {
    let app:App;

    beforeEach((done) => {
        console.log(bootstrap);
        bootstrap(<Type>App)
            .then(result => result.instance)
            .then(instance => {
                app = instance;
                done();
            });
    });

    it('Test for App to Exist', (done) => {
        console.log(app);
        done();
    });
});
```

As best I can tell, the `console.log(bootstrap)` fails somehow, as my gulp-mocha task just dies (silently). Commenting out the bootstrap references to just do a dummy test;

```
import {bootstrap} from 'angular2/platform/browser';
import {App} from '../app/app';
import {Type} from 'angular2/core';

describe('Login', () => {
    let app:App;

    beforeEach((done) => {
        done();
    });

    it('Test for App to Exist', (done) => {
        console.log(app);
        done();
    });
});
```

Logs an `undefined` as I would expect. Has anyone managed to get something like this to work? The goal here is unit-testing controllers, so I'm trying really hard to avoid phantomJS/webdriver/etc.

Answer (score -4):

I think that mocha can't be used directly because it runs on node only (maybe it would be possible with Angular2 universal when you just render HTML strings server side). That being said, you can use [mochify](https://github.com/mantoni/mochify.js) which is mocha with browserify used in a background. I am working on a [example project](https://github.com/tomastrajan/complete-angular2-seed) for that setup.

Test then can look something like this:

```
// import everything needed for to run Angular (we're running in PhantomJS by defualt but other browsers are possible too)
import "es6-shim";
import "es6-promise";
import "zone.js";
import "rxjs";
import "reflect-metadata";

import "../../typings/browser.d.ts";

import {Injector, enableProdMode} from "angular2/core";
import {HTTP_PROVIDERS} from "angular2/http";


// import stuff we need to instantiate component
import GithubComponent from "./gihub-component";
import GithubService from "./github-service";
import Config from "../config";

import * as sinon from "sinon";

enableProdMode();

describe("github-component", () => {

    let injector: Injector;
    let component: any;
    let service: any;

    beforeEach(() => {
        // instantiate Angular 2 DI context
        injector = Injector.resolveAndCreate([
            HTTP_PROVIDERS,
            GithubComponent,
            GithubService,
            Config
        ]);
        component = injector.get(GithubComponent);
        service = injector.get(GithubService);
        sinon.spy(service, "getRepos");
    });

    afterEach(() => {
        service.getRepos.restore();
    });

    it("searches for repository", () => {
        component.query.updateValue("test");

        return setTimeout(() => {
            sinon.assert.calledOnce(service.getRepos);
            sinon.assert.calledWith(service.getRepos, "test");
        }, 300);
    });

});
```